# ORA-02289: sequence does not exist when upgrade Hibernate 3 to hibernate 4

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, sequence

I have an issue related to sequence not found when I upgrade hibernate from 3.5 to 4.0.0.RC6:

```
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:703) [hibernate-core-4.0.0.CR6.jar:4.0.0.CR6]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:707) [hibernate-core-4.0.0.CR6.jar:4.0.0.CR6]
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:847) [hibernate-entitymana
ger-4.0.0.CR6.jar:4.0.0.CR6]
... 159 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:91)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:206)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:455)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:413)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:1034)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:194)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:791)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:866)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1186)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3387)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3431)
```

Anyone know how to fix it? please let me know. I am using Oracle10gDialect and override getNativeIdentifierGeneratorClass() function by using my own SequenceGenerator. It has worked on Hibernate 3.5 but thrown exception when I upgrade to Hibernate 4.0.0.RC6

Below is my TableNameSequenceGenerator class:

```
public class TableNameSequenceGenerator extends SequenceGenerator {

    public void configure(Type type, Properties params, Dialect dialect) throws MappingException {
        if(params.getProperty(SEQUENCE) == null || params.getProperty(SEQUENCE).length() == 0) {
            String tableName = params.getProperty(PersistentIdentifierGenerator.TABLE);
            if(tableName != null) {
                String seqName = tableName + "_SEQ";
                params.setProperty(SEQUENCE, seqName);               
            }
        }
        super.configure(type, params, dialect);
    }
}
```

When I do debugging by using hibernate 4, tableName return REVINFO only (it works in hibernate 3)

Thanks
Hiep

Comment: What does your SequenceGenerator do?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.

For common id generator for all classes, we should use

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="GENERATOR_COMMON")
@GenericGenerator(name="GENERATOR_COMMON",strategy="point.to.table.generator")
```

Hope this help someone who have the same issue like me.

Answer (score 0):

Even i got the same issue, Use the following lines

```
@GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
```