# SQLGrammarException with Hibernated and oracle11g

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I am merely trying to fetch a row of information from the CONTACTS table from my oracle sql database and I get this error :

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02289: la séquence n'existe pas (non existing sequence)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1017)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:655)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:249)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:566)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:215)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:58)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:776)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:897)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1034)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3820)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3867)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1502)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:116)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:80)
... 12 more
```

Java Result: 1

My Contacts.hbm.xml file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="Contacts" table="CONTACTS">
    <id name="id_contact" type="integer" column="IDCONTACTS">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="nom" column="NOM" type="string" length="20"/>
    <property name="prenom" column="PRENOM" type="string" length="20"/>
    <property name="email" column="EMAIL" type="string" length="20"/>
    <property name="salaire" column="SALAIRE" type="integer" length="12"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">
        org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
        adresse...
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
        login
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
        psswrd
    </property>

    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>

    <mapping class="Contacts" file="" jar="" package="" resource="Contacts.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and Contacts.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;
public class Contacts implements Serializable {  
    private int id_contact;
    private String nom, prenom, email;
    private float salaire;

    public Contacts(){
    }
    public int getId_contact() {
        return id_contact;
    }

    public void setId_contact(int id_contact) {
        this.id_contact = id_contact;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public String getPrenom() {
        return prenom;
    }

    public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
        this.prenom = prenom;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public float getSalaire() {
        return salaire;
    }

    public void setSalaire(float salaire) {
        this.salaire = salaire;
    }
}
```

The error occurs when I call

```
 session.save(contact1) 
 //contact1 has been using setters to populate its fields.
```

And my table on sqlplus look like this

```
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 IDCONTACT                                 NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
 NOM                                                VARCHAR2(20)
 PRENOM                                             VARCHAR2(20)
 EMAIL                                              VARCHAR2(20)
 SALAIRE                                            NUMBER(12)
```

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177779/ora-02289-sequence-does-not-exist-when-upgrade-hibernate-3-to-hibernate-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you've created the table manually (without hibernate).

As you didn't declare the sequence name here

```
<id name="id_contact" type="integer" column="IDCONTACTS">
    <generator class="native"/>
</id>
```

Hibernate tries to use a sequence named HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE

So you need to create HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE in your DB or define your sequence explicitly:

```
<id name="id_contact" type="integer" column="IDCONTACTS">
    <generator class="native">
       <param name="sequence">CONTACTS_SEQ</param>
    </generator>
</id>
```

Comment: What should I put in place of CONTACTS_SEQ ? Should I add anything on the table manually ?

Comment: @maximegir Your sequence name. You should create an Oracle sequence